# Word for a small taste of drink

Tags: word-meaning, translation, regional, single-words

My Italian family members will use a word that sounds like "spudatza" to refer to a small taste of a drink.

"Would you like to try this wine?"

"Just a spudatza"

What word is this?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your Italian family members are saying *sputazza* which is a word coming from Sicilian dialect and it literally means *sputo* (spit), and also *saliva* (saliva, spittle).

Obviously the meaning is what you guessed: a colloquial form to indicate a small taste of drink.

Comment: This has to be correct - they're from Sicily